# Why does Google Chrome automatically play MP4 videos (and is that a good thing?)

Tags: google-chrome, vlc-media-player, streaming, nginx, mp4

I am working on a home media server running nginx. I navigated to one of the `.mp4` files I have to test it and it started streaming just by clicking on it.

Is this... performance-wise... the best solution? Should I try something along the lines of VLC or a browser-based JWPlayer?

I have already optimized nginx with http_mp4 and http_flv modules. They seem to run like a charm.